# SearchBox doesn't fire QuerySubmitted one phone when clicking search icon(UWP 10)

Tags: c#, win-universal-app, uwp, search-box

I have a SearchBox that works fine on desktop. When clicking on icon the QuerySubmitted event is fired.

However on phone this is not the case. With the KeyUp event i can get the enter from the keyboard UI but that doesn't help me with the issue of the icon not working.

```
<SearchBox PlaceholderText="" QuerySubmitted="SearchBox_QuerySubmitted" QueryChanged="SearchBox_QueryChanged">        
</SearchBox>
```

Code behind

```
    private void SearchBox_QuerySubmitted(SearchBox sender, SearchBoxQuerySubmittedEventArgs args)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("SearchBox_QuerySubmitted");
    }

    private void SearchBox_QueryChanged(SearchBox sender, SearchBoxQueryChangedEventArgs args)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("SearchBox_QueryChanged");
    }
```

Is this a bug or is this intended?
Is there a work around?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For UWP you should use AutoSuggestBox:

To use an AutoSuggestBox, you need to respond to 3 user actions.

•Text changed - When the user enters text, update the suggestion list.

•Suggestion chosen - When the user chooses a suggestion in the suggestion list, update the text box.

•Query submitted - When the user submits a query, show the query results.

Query submitted will be raised properly on phone. I just tested it.

More info here : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.autosuggestbox.aspx

Comment: Thanks for the response. I will try that. However why doesn't searchbox work?

Comment: About AutoSuggestBox in W10:

The Windows 8.1 functionality equivalent for this would be SearchBox, which allows you to do suggestions. AutoSuggestBox is lightweight, without Search integration, and suggestions in a list with ItemsControl. A sample can be found on Settings.xaml page for phone.

Read more at https://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2014/07/22/tips-and-tricks-for-using-xaml-controls-in-your-universal-windows-apps/#SXxqbCKrwGtVUYx5.99 Can you please mark as answer ? Thanks ! :)